# Android - generating PKCS#10 requests

Tags: android, ssl, bouncycastle, pkcs#12, pkcs#10

I'm trying to create certificate requests according to PKCS#10.
X509v3 Key Usage should be set to: Digital Signature, Key Encipherment.

This is what I've found so far, but since I use latest bouncycastle (1.52) the X509Extension.keyUsage is deprecated.

```
public static PKCS10CertificationRequest generateCSRFile(KeyPair keyPair, KeyUsage keyUsage) throws IOException, OperatorCreationException {
    String principal = "CN=" + Utils.getCertificateCommonName() + ", O=" + Utils.getCertificateOrganization();
    AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
    AlgorithmIdentifier signatureAlgorithm = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("SHA1WITHRSA");
    AlgorithmIdentifier digestAlgorithm = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("SHA-1");
    ContentSigner signer = new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(signatureAlgorithm, digestAlgorithm).build(privateKey);

    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder csrBuilder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(new X500Name(principal), keyPair.getPublic());
    ExtensionsGenerator extensionsGenerator = new ExtensionsGenerator();
    extensionsGenerator.addExtension(X509Extension.basicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(true));
    extensionsGenerator.addExtension(X509Extension.keyUsage, true, keyUsage);
    csrBuilder.addAttribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest, extensionsGenerator.generate());
    PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = csrBuilder.build(signer);

    return csr;
}
```

Is there another way to add KeyUsage?

Basically this is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Generate certificate requests with PKCS#10
2. Create two certificates from two keypairs (Digital Signature + Key Encipherment and Non Repudiation).
3. Save the private keys from the certificate requests in PKCS#12.

I'm quite new when it comes to cryptography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you? X509Extension seems to be replaceable with Extension. Not sure on the Android context though.

```
public static PKCS10CertificationRequest generateCSRFile(KeyPair keyPair, KeyUsage keyUsage) throws IOException, OperatorCreationException {
    String principal = "CN=" + Utils.getCertificateCommonName() + ", O=" + Utils.getCertificateOrganization();
    AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
    AlgorithmIdentifier signatureAlgorithm = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("SHA1WITHRSA");
    AlgorithmIdentifier digestAlgorithm = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("SHA-1");
    ContentSigner signer = new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(signatureAlgorithm, digestAlgorithm).build(privateKey);

    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder csrBuilder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(new X500Name(principal), keyPair.getPublic());
    ExtensionsGenerator extensionsGenerator = new ExtensionsGenerator();
    extensionsGenerator.addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(true));
    extensionsGenerator.addExtension(Extension.keyUsage, true, keyUsage);
    csrBuilder.addAttribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest, extensionsGenerator.generate());
    PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = csrBuilder.build(signer);

    return csr;
}
```

Comment: is there any way to achive CSR with out using BouncyCastle libs ot any other libs in android ?